# attribute extraction using Xpath

Tags: java, xml, xpath

I have an XML as Java String:

```
String abc = "<Tags  Value = '635' Type = 'Number'/>";
```

I am trying to extract the `Value` of such an XML object using Xpath

What I tried until now is something like this:

```
InputSource doc = new InputSource(abc);
XPath xPath =  XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();
XPathExpression expr = xPath.compile("/Tags[@Value]");
System.out.println(expr.evaluate(doc));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try it

```
public class Example {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException, XPathExpressionException {
        String abc = "<Tags  Value = '635' Type = 'Number'/>";
        InputSource doc = new InputSource(new StringReader(abc));
        XPath xPath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();
        XPathExpression expr = xPath.compile("/Tags/@Value");
        System.out.println(expr.evaluate(doc)); // 635
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 InputSource doc = new InputSource(abc);
 XPath xPath =  XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();
 XPathExpression expr = xPath.compile("/Tags/@Value");
 System.out.println(expr.evaluate(doc));
```

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.net.MalformedURLException: no protocol: <Tags  Value = '635' Type = 'Number'/>

Comment: `/Tags/@Value]` have you double-checked that syntax?